# How to pass the data from a radio box in one Activity to a series of Checkboxes in another

Tags: android

I need to pass the value selected in a `RadioGroup` on one `Activity` to a series of 5 `CheckBoxs` in another.
I don't know enough about Global Variables to be able to just do this myself

So I have 5 `RadioButtons` in a `RadioGroup` in my `XML`, like this:

```
 <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/rdoInternet1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Dedicated and Resilient"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

And then in my Java I was going to a series of Nested if statements

```
        //find the id of the RadioGroup and store it in a variable
        RadioGroup question1RadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioInternet);
        question1RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            //set a listener on the RadioGroup
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup view, @IdRes int checkedId) {
                //checkedId refers to the selected RadioButton
                //Perform an action based on the option chosen
                if (checkedId == R.id.rdoInternet1) {
                    /*Nested if statement setting value 1 */
                } else {
                    if (checkedId == R.id.rdoInternet2) {
                        /*Nested if statement setting value 1 */
                    } else {
                        if (checkedId == R.id.rdoInternet3) {
                            /*Nested if statement setting value 1 */
                        } else {
                            if (checkedId == R.id.rdoInternet4) {
                                /*Nested if statement setting value 1 */
                            } else {
                                if (checkedId == R.id.rdoInternet5) {
                                    /*Nested if statement setting value 1 */
```

But then I don't know how to store it as a global variable and then would have recalled this in the next screen using nested ifs again to say which `checkbox` to Check.

So what I need to know is, is there a better way to do this and how to store up the Global Value

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is adding boolean variables as intent extra :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", true);
```

and then get it in your next activity :

```
Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");
```